How to register files that changed with ansible.posix.synchronize in Ansible
I have the following task that copy certain files from a host to another:
- name: Copy the Quadlet files for rootless containers
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: ./files/quadlet-files/homeserver/
    dest: /home/user/.config/containers/systemd/
    rsync_opts:
      - '--include=*.container'
      - '--exclude=*'
      - '--chmod=D700,F600'
  register: changed_quadlet_files
  notify:
    - Restart container(s)
   

I'd like to have a handler that takes as input the name of the files that have changed without the .container extension
Something like this:
- name: Restart container(s)
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: restarted
    scope: user
  loop:
    -  LIST_FROM_SYNCRONIZE_TASK

Is it possible?

Unfortunately, you can't format the output because of the bug. But, you can parse the output on your own. For example, given the tree for testing
shell> tree /tmp/ansible/
/tmp/ansible/
├── dest
└── src
    ├── a
    ├── b
    └── c

Register the output
    - synchronize:
        src: /tmp/ansible/src/
        dest: /tmp/ansible/dest
      register: out
      notify: Restart containers

gives
  out:
    changed: true
    cmd: /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /tmp/ansible/src/ /tmp/ansible/dest
    failed: false
    msg: |-
      .d..t...... ./
      >f+++++++++ a
      >f+++++++++ b
      >f+++++++++ c
    rc: 0
    stdout_lines:
    - .d..t...... ./
    - '>f+++++++++ a'
    - '>f+++++++++ b'
    - '>f+++++++++ c'

Parse the output
  changed_files: "{{ out.stdout_lines |
                     select('match', '>f') |
                     map('split') |
                     map('last') }}"

and use it in the handler. For example,
    - name: Restart containers
      debug:
        msg: "Restart {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ changed_files }}"

gives
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) => 
  msg: Restart a
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) => 
  msg: Restart b
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) => 
  msg: Restart c



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    changed_files: "{{ out.stdout_lines |
                       select('match', '>f') |
                       map('split') |
                       map('last') }}"

  tasks:

    - synchronize:
        src: /tmp/ansible/src/
        dest: /tmp/ansible/dest
      register: out
      notify: Restart containers

  handlers:
    
    - name: Restart containers
      debug:
        msg: "Restart {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ changed_files }}"


